# Server-Sent Events sending ping(comment) processed by client side

Tags: javascript, php, server-sent-events

My server side script is listening for notifications from database and sends them to the client. Every 30 seconds checks and if there are no notifications sends a ping(comment) message. There is a keepAliveTimer on the client side which checks if there are incoming message from the server for 40 seconds and if there are no messages to reset the connection.

My question is how to get(processed) a ping(comment) message?

I don't want to send a ping message with SSE data line with id, event and data because of two things:

1. The size of the packet is bigger.
2. HTTP_LAST_EVENT_ID to be only for notifications not for ping messages

I think @Darren Cook would be great to comment :)

**Server side:**

```
while (1) {
        
  $result = ""; 
  $result = $dbconn->pgsqlGetNotify(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, 30000);

  if ( $result ) {
        $inc++;
    $payload = json_decode($result["payload"],true);
    echo "id: $inc\n";
    echo "event: ".$result["message"]."\n"; 
    echo "data: ".$result["payload"]."\n\n";        
  } else {
    echo ":\n\n"; // ping       
  }
        
  flush();
  ob_end_flush();
  if (connection_aborted()) {
    error_log ("Script was aborted by the user.");
    $dbconn->exec('UNLISTEN "test"');
        break;
  }
}
```

**Client Side:**

```
var url = "test.php";
var source = null;
var keepaliveSecs = 40;
var keepAliveTimer = null;

function gotActivity() {
  if (keepAliveTimer  != null) { clearTimeout(keepAliveTimer ); };
  keepAliveTimer  = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("SSE No Activity");
    setupEventSource();
}, keepaliveSecs * 1000);
}

function setupEventSource() { 
  if (source) { source.close(); }
  gotActivity();
  var source = new EventSource(url);
  
  source.onmessage = function() {
       console.log("SSE onmessage");
       gotActivity();
  }
 
   
  source.onerror = function(event) {
        switch( event.target.readyState ){
                            case EventSource.CONNECTING:
                                console.log('Reconnecting...');
                                break;
                            case EventSource.CLOSED:
                                console.log('Connection failed. Will not retry.');
                                source.close();
                                setTimeout(setupEventSource, 10000)
                                break;
                            default:
                                console.log(event);
                                break;
        }
  }
    
}
setupEventSource();
```

Comment: seems wholly unnecessary to be closing and re-opening EventSource connection every N seconds ~ is there some benefit to resetting the connection repeatedly? Strange that a small increase in packet size is perceived as worse than dropping/reconnection the SSE connection

Comment: It is only dropped if there are no message from server (notification or ping). That checks if connection is okey.